# Windows Server AD: How can I keep userdata off of the local computer?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2022

I would like to get Roaming Profiles to delete the user profile once they log off. How could I get this working as I don't want any userdata stored on the local pc (i.e. having 20 different AD user profile folders created in the C:\Users directory).

Comment: I know this doesn’t answer the question, but the use of roaming profiles is obsolete and are notoriously problematic since Win 8. There are far better ways to do this now. Microsoft has already announced the deprecation of legacy roaming profiles. You would do well to modernize.

Comment: @Appleoddity do you have any recommendations for alternatives (apart from folder redirection).

Comment: You can explore enterprise state roaming, and user experience virtualization with OneDrive storage and folder redirection. There are a number of limitations now to legacy roaming profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Group Policy endpoint setting "Delete cached copies of roaming profiles".

Computer > System> User Profiles

https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_7_2008R2&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.UserProfiles::DeleteRoamingCachedProfiles

Comment: So I just tried this and it works, however when I log off and log back in again, it says "Can't log in to this account" when I reach the desktop and just logs me into a temporary account.

Comment: @Anonymous: roaming profiles and their removal are known to be problematic. When logging off, if there are open handles to any file it can prevent proper removal.

Comment: Are there any other alternatives to Roaming Profiles (apart from Folder Redirection which also doesn't backup anything)